# Need help to download a file from a Web URL after certain delay

Tags: java

I have to write a small Java program to download a file from a given server URL. However, the URL actually returns the file after 2-3 minutes. Before that, the program has already returned a response with an empty file. 
What I need is that the program should wait(pause its execution) after making the hit to the URL. After waiting for a few minutes, it can check again.
I have tried doing this via Thread.sleep and other waiting modes but it does not seem to work. It keeps giving me an empty file. 
Note that I have gone through a lot of existing threads before asking this question. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of what you tried so far?

Comment: Is this a public url you can provide?

Comment: I don't see how you could use a _sleep_ to solve your problem. Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

from my perspective, you can use "handler" and then you can create an object of "post delayed" method to delay the process. Like, we use "post delayed" method to delay the activity or a button in Android.

You can check this video, it will help you. Thank you.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pgGVBmSVq0][1]

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this could be done using Thread.sleep(time) . The time should be equal or greater than the server delay time.